# Restricting Google Cloud Endpoints with API key

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints-v2, ibm-api-management

I'm using Google Cloud Endpoints v2 for java. I create endpoints method and restrict it through API. After this, I create API from GCP console.

I'm calling endpoints method from android using client libs. Here is how I'm calling any method.

```
   APIName.Builder builder = new APIName.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), null);
    APIName apiName = builder.build();

   apiName .account().checkRegistration(phone).setKey(ApiKey).execute();
```

And it always give and error.

> 403 Requests from this Android client application  are blocked.

It's seems there is some kind of problem in my sha-1 or in package name I double check everything all are good.

I create sha-1 using this `keytool -list -v -keystore "Key store path" -alias "Key Name"` and set into API as shown in image.

Then I also try to get sha-1 through android studio `Gradle->AppName->android->signingReport` it give me different sha-1 I also add it and try but still same error.

I add these and wait more than 2 hours still same error.

What I'm doing wrong. ?

[image]